# Store value in stdout from popen3 in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, popen

**How can I store the string value in `stdout` from the following Ruby code?**

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = Open3.popen3('grep something test.txt')
```

I can display the value like this: `stdout.gets`. However trying to store the value like this: `s = stdout.gets` just sets `s` to `nil`. Trying to store the value like this: `s = stdout` stores something like `"#<IO:0x1003abe10>"` in `s`.

Comment: Are you trying to execute `s = stdout.gets` after executing `stout.gets`?

Comment: I don't think so. I'd just like to store the value in stdout in a string. Next I'd do something like `s.chomp("\n")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`output = stdout.read` seems to work.

Comment: That's weird. I have no problem using `stdout.gets`.

Comment: `gets` returns the current line. But at the end of file, `gets` returns `nil`. That is why the OP is getting `nil`. It just depends on the length of the data.

Answer (score 1):

`Open3.capture3`  might be what you want; it gives you strings from STDOUT and STDERR, and the status of the process:

```
outstr, errstr, status = Open3.capture3('/bin/command-here', param, param2)
logger.info 'output: ' + outstr + '; error: ' + errstr 
             + "; " return code: " + status.exitstatus.to_s
```